# ios how to save json data call as file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json

Any of you knows how can I save a json data call into a file?

```
self.results=[NSJSONSerialization
                           JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                           options:0
                           error:&error];
```

I tried:

```
 [_results writeToFile:@"jsonFile" atomically:YES];
```

But I don't see the file:

NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error];

```
file path (
    "Default-568h@2x.png",
    "Default.png",
    "Default@2x.png",
    "en.lproj",
    "Info.plist",
    "JSON Generator",
    PkgInfo
)
```

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Why `- [NSData writeToFile:atomically:]` isn't good enough? Or the same with `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, etc.?

Comment: Yep, just use `writeToFile` for either the `jsonData`, or `self.results`. Either is fine.

Answer (score 1):

`JSONObjectWithData` returns either an `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` or nil. If not nil write it with:

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```